# F# beginner using let on multiple dependent names

Tags: f#, let

I hate to ask such a noob question, but I have hunted high and low online--and this is literally my first day.

The following VBA excerpt assigns two variables, where the first variable feeds into the second variable (this code is from www.spreadsheetadvice.com):

```
If zabs <= 12.7 Then
    ...
    If zabs <= 1.28 Then
        Temp = y + a3 - a4 / (y + a5 + a6 / (y + a7))
        Q = a0 - zabs * (a1 - a2 * y / Temp)
    Else
        Temp = (zabs - b5 + b6 / (zabs + b7 - b8 / (zabs + b9 + b10 / (zabs + b11))))
        Q = pdF / (zabs - b1 + (b2 / (zabs + b3 + b4 / Temp)))
    End If
Else ...
```

I'm trying to replicate it in F#--without using mutables. This works:

```
    let Temp = 
        if zabs <= 1.28 then
            y + a3 - a4 / (y + a5 + a6 / (y + a7))
        elif zabs <= 12.7 then
            (zabs - b5 + b6 / (zabs + b7 - b8 / (zabs + b9 + b10 / (zabs + b11))))
        else
            0.0

    let Q = 
        if zabs <= 1.28 then
            a0 - zabs * (a1 - a2 * y / Temp)
        elif zabs <= 12.7 then
            pdF / (zabs - b1 + (b2 / (zabs + b3 + b4 / Temp)))
        else
            0.0
```

But I don't like separating the two related variables--or repeating the If statements. This doesn't work but is as close as I've come:

```
    let Temp, Q = 
        if zabs <= 1.28 then
            y + a3 - a4 / (y + a5 + a6 / (y + a7)),
            a0 - zabs * (a1 - a2 * y / Temp)
        elif zabs <= 12.7 then
            (zabs - b5 + b6 / (zabs + b7 - b8 / (zabs + b9 + b10 / (zabs + b11)))),
            pdF / (zabs - b1 + (b2 / (zabs + b3 + b4 / Temp)))
        else
            0.0,
            0.0
```

It took me a while to figure out the commas on the 3rd, 6th, and 9th lines (if they are in fact right). But the compiler thinks I am trying to use Temp before it is assigned. I assume, or hope, I'm just missing a simple idiom.

Comment: Of course, it must be a function: let func = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was making a simple mistake: because Temp is temporary and subordinate to Q, then Temp should be declared with a scope local to the declaration of Q, not with equal scope as Q. With that figured out, I think using If and using Match work equally well. But Match is probably more idiomatic (thanks Alessandro). Thusly:

```
    let Q =             
        match zabs with
        | i when i <= 1.28 ->
            let Temp = y + a3 - a4 / (y + a5 + a6 / (y + a7))
            a0 - zabs * (a1 - a2 * y / Temp)
        | i when i <= 12.7 ->
            let Temp = (zabs - b5 + b6 / (zabs + b7 - b8 / (zabs + b9 + b10 / (zabs + b11))))
            pdF / (zabs - b1 + (b2 / (zabs + b3 + b4 / Temp)))
        | _ ->
            0.0
```

So now I'm bound to want to make two declarations that do need to be of the same scope some time soon and come back to a similar situation again...

Comment: `match x with i when i > 0` is neither more idiomatic nor clearer than `if x > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
let Temp, Q = 
    if zabs <= 1.28 then
        let temp = y + a3 - a4 / (y + a5 + a6 / (y + a7))
        let q = a0 - zabs * (a1 - a2 * y / temp)
        temp, q
    elif zabs <= 12.7 then
        let temp = (zabs - b5 + b6 / (zabs + b7 - b8 / (zabs + b9 + b10 / (zabs + b11))))
        let q = pdF / (zabs - b1 + (b2 / (zabs + b3 + b4 / temp)))
        temp, q
    else
        0.0, 0.0
```

Comment: I like this and it's clearly better than the best answer I made. But I'm hoping I can be more direct and not use intermediate names. I'm trying Alessandro's way.

Answer (score 1):

> It took me a while to figure out the commas on the 3rd, 6th, and 9th lines (if they are in fact right). But the compiler thinks I am trying to use Temp before it is assigned. I assume, or hope, I'm just missing a simple idiom.

Yes, you are missing the basics of the language, you must put the commas because you declare a `tuple` so you have to bind a value of type `'a * 'b`

I suggest to use *pattern matching*, one of the more powerful thing of F# (and other functional languages) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx

```
let yourfunc zabs = 
    match zabs with
    | x when x <= 1.28   -> let temp = y + a3 - a4 / (y + a5 + a6 / (y + a7))
                            let q = a0 - zabs * (a1 - a2 * y / temp)
                            temp, q
    | x when x <= 12.7   -> let temp = (zabs - b5 + b6 / (zabs + b7 - b8 / (zabs + b9 + b10 / (zabs + b11))))
                            let q = pdF / (zabs - b1 + (b2 / (zabs + b3 + b4 / temp)))
                            temp, q
    | _ -> 0.0,0.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Pattern matching crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure it fit with inequalities. I'll try some variations on this too. Hopefully it only takes a couple formative moments to start to get the sense of the language.